# Virtuemart only add first products you add and the stop to add products

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I use virtuemart 2.6.x, with joomla latest joomla 2 version. When i add products to cart the first products i add, they added correctly but after some products i add it stop to add products. I have tried different template and the same problem happend. I think it is a problem with server setting and related to cookies

The get request generated but product not added to cart

```
http://www.foo.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json&customPlugin%5B11765%5D%5Bstockable%5D%5Bselectoptions1%5D=%CE%9C%CE%B1%CF%8D%CF%81%CE%BF&customPlugin%5B11765%5D%5Bstockable%5D%5Bselectoptions2%5D=0.5mm&customPlugin%5B11765%5D%5Bstockable%5D%5Bchild_id%5D=1739&customPrice%5B1%5D%5B64%5D=11765&quantity%5B%5D=1&option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&virtuemart_product_id%5B%5D=1741&_=1519390547340
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think it's a server setting try it local, or if you're working local, upload it and you will see. Have you recently updated Virtuemart? If yes, try to undo it, go back to the older version and see if it's working. 
But I really suggest that you update to Joomla 3.8 and to the latest Virtuemart.

Comment: check and compare the settings local and on server.  Probably some PHP setting/version issue I think..

Comment: I use the same php version and I check settings to be identical